# maven enforcer enforce class path order

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, classpath, maven-enforcer-plugin

Suppose I have a maven module M which declares a direct dependency on modules X and Y.  I want the classes from X to come before classes from Y in the class path.  Is there any easy way to add a rule in maven enforcer to ensure that if I don't accidentally swap the order sometime in the future?

### The question itself is now complete.  Everything below this line is me trying to explain why I want this.

We have a multi-module maven project.  Most modules depend on `protobuf-java:2.4.1` but some depend on 2.5 instead of 2.4.  The ones that depend on 2.5 also depend on those that need 2.4.  Sadly, the `protobuf` maintainers at Google made a big mistake, which they claim they will not repeat again.  The mistake was that they decided that breaking ABI is okay, as long they don't break API.

In particular, in version 2.4 some methods in the class `TextFormat` take an argument of type `Message` whereas in 2.5 they take an argument of type `MessageOrBuilder` which is more general.  This means that if 2.5 is on the runtime class path, any module compiled against 2.4 will crash with `NoSuchMethodError` if it tries to call such a method.

My solution was to create another module which contains my own copy of `TextFormat.java` (and doesn't contain anything else).  My copy adds back the methods that take `Message` which were removed in 2.5.  I'm adding that module as a runtime dependency to those modules which need 2.5, so as "simulate" a version of 2.5 which is backwards-compatible with 2.4.

I want to add a maven enforcer rule to ensure that this hacky "compat" module always comes before the official module in the class path, so that my fix gets picked up.

Comment: Why exactly would you need that behaviour? Even if Maven has some order of classpath entries, your IDE might order them differently.

Comment: My IDE respects maven ordering I believe.  (If not, that's a bug.)  Why do I want this?  Long story, which this comment box is too small too contain.  (Actually that's not true... I can squeeze it in if you want to know.)  But basically: module `Y` is a third party dependency, and module `X` is our own module which contains an "improved" version of one of the classes from Y so that it does the Right Thing instead of the Wrong Thing.

Comment: If you rely on class path ordering there is something wrong. If your own module contains improved versions you should rename them to prevent classhes ... or it might be a good idea to offer improvements to the project Y.... or creating a version 2 of module Y or very bad would be to fork project Y and change the artifactId and version...

Comment: Project Y has learned its lesson and newer versions no longer repeat the same mistake.  However, newer versions are not backward compatible with the version I'm on, so this doesn't help me very much.

Comment: Re: name clashes: the name clash is the whole point!  I need to ensure my class gets loaded instead of the official one.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you assume that if I'm doing something "dumb" it's because there are constraints involved that I didn't bother to explain, because it would make the question much longer, and then no one would read it.